# .Net Ticks to ISO 8601 Date format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net, mongodb, datetimeoffset

I am saving DateTimeOffset object in MongoDB. Mongo driver serilizes DateTimeOffset as following.

```
[635519027206007023,0]
```

I need it to be converted to ISO 8601 format as follows.

```
2015-02-02T01:43:19+05:00
```

Conversion can be easily done using help of .NET DateTimeOffset class. But, in this case I am retrieving DateTimeOffset directly from MongoDB using JavaScript (Node.js). Hence I end up retrieving array of long.

How can I convert array of longs `[635519027206007023,0]` to ISO 8601 format `2015-02-02T01:43:19+00:00` using `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The epoch for the `DateTimeOffset` type is 0000-01-01, while the epoch for Javascript dates is 1970-01-01.

The `DateTimeOffset` ticks value for the date 1970-01-01 is 621355968000000000, so you can just subtract that from the value to convert it to the Javascript epoch.

Ticks in `DateTimeOffset` is 1/10000000 second, while ticks in Javascript dates is 1/1000 second, so divide the value by 10000 to convert it to Javascript date ticks.

So, to get the Javascript date from the `DateTimeOffset` ticks:

```
new Date((date[0] - 621355968000000000) / 10000)
```

Then you can use the [`toISOString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to convert the date to an ISO8601 string.